# How does WPF get the Rendering Tier of a Machine?

Tags: .net, wpf, rendering

I am using `System.Windows.Media.RenderCapability.Tier` to get the Rendering Tier of the machine my WPF application is running on but I would like to know how it gets this information. I'm looking for information like:
Does it use Com componets?
Does it use Direct X?
Does it use DDE?
Does it use Windows Message loop?
Does it get the result in a different way if Hardware Rendering is disabled on the graphics card?

I'm using .Net3.5 on Windows Xp if that has any bearing on the answer (I would be interested in how it works on Windows 7 if it is different).

Thanks

Comment: To confirm, you want to know not [what determines the tiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx), but how the information is gathered by the OS?  If so, that could be a mighty difficult question to answer accurately.  [This article](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/netc-%E2%80%93-determining-the-hardware-acceleration-support-for-your-wpf-apps/) any use to you?

Comment: Yes, I want to know who that information is gathered by the CLR/OS. I had a feeling it might be a hard question to answer.

Comment: I think you might get a better response if you break the question down.  You can see (at least vaguely) what determines the tiers in the previous articles I linked.  From there, pick a component of the formula (Hardware Acceleration for example) and post a question asking how to detect whether Hardware Acceleration is enabled.  Otherwise you might need a bounty on this question to spur people on... - it is a lot of work

Comment: As a quick caveat... Obviously it pays off to at least attempt each part yourself, before searching online for a solution, and before posting a question here. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses DirectX to query the capabilities of the graphics hardware.  The video memory and other supported DirectX capabilities (for example, via [D3DCAPS9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) determine the decision based on [the rules that are described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx).

Comment: I can't be sure, but I suspect something like this API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174320(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Does that answer your question?